# Testing nested Angular directives with Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, tdd, bdd

I have a custom angular directive (top level directive), that passes values to 2 other directives (sub directives), within it's template body.

I have to write an integration test, if the sub directives are receiving proper values passed by the top level directive, however when I $compile(topLevelDirectiveHtml)(scope), it's HTML doesn't contain the evaluated values, but instead of evaluated HTML within the sub directives, I get just the template, containing a reference to the model... To give an example:

```
$scope.myModel = true;
<topLevelDirective testValue="myModel" />
```

After compilation this evaluates to the following code

```
directive.scope.subValue = myModel;
<subDirective subTestValue="subValue" />
```

I need to verify that after the compilation of the subDirective, the "subTestValue" attribute has a value of "true", but instead its value is "subValue"

Comment: Can you provide a little more detail on your directives, both their templates and the angularjs declarations for them?

Answer (score 0):

You must asign  "subValue" on your scope fake like:

```
scopeFake.subValue = true;
```